# How to prevent html content that's passed into sfFormField::renderRow() from getting escaped?

Tags: forms, view, symfony1

In a symfony 1.4 view I'm attempting to pass some html/javascript in the "attributes" parameter of the `sfFormField::renderRow` function:

```
<?php echo $form['ownership_status_id']->renderRow(array('onFocus' => 'displayHelp("<p>help text</p>");'), 'Own/Rent')?>
```

Unfortuantely the when the page gets rendered, all of the javascript/html output is escaped:

```
<select name="address[ownership_status_id]" onFocus="displayHelp(&quot;(&quot;&lt;p&gt;help text&lt;/p&gt;&quot;);" id="address_ownership_status_id">
```

I'm not clear on how to prevent this content from being escaped, can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to unescape the $form variable as so:

```
sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator::unescape($form);
```

Then call renderRow():

```
<?php echo $form['ownership_status_id']->renderRow(array('onFocus' => 'displayHelp("<p>help text</p>");'), 'Own/Rent'); ?>
```

Comment: I added that call at the top of the view, but it didn't seem to have any effect. The javascript/html is still escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this:

```
<?php echo sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator::unescape($form['ownership_status_id']->renderRow(array('onFocus' => 'displayHelp("<p>help text</p>");'), 'Own/Rent')); ?>
```